# Adding multilines to a node in FreeMind

Tags: freemind

I am using verison 0.9.0 for FreeMind.

Am trying to add mutli lines to a node. Have tried alt+enter, edit using long node and simple enter. This did not work.

For e.g

```
just checking if I can split this line into multi lines.
```

I would like to split above line into two for the same node.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Alt+Enter` when editing the node should work. You'll get an extended editor pop-up which lets you have multi lines. In that editor, you just need to press enter when you want a newline, like normal editors.